# react-admin conditional rendering on select field

Tags: react-admin

I got stuck a little bit:

I've got Field A which is for querying the projects (Select field -> ReferenceInput) when the user hits this, we should only show the user on Field B (Select Field -> ReferenceInput) the relevant tasks based on the projectId.

How could I achieve this?

[Link to image to visualise the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNtKR.png)

Answer (score 1):

What you’re looking for is the useFormState or FormDataConsumer. Take a look in the docs and let me know if you have any other questions related.

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#linking-two-inputs